# Showing command line output without all of the newlines

Tags: matlab

Let's just say I type `2+3` in MATLAB. It gives me this output :

```
>> 2+3

ans =

     5
```

Why is the output coming after 2 newlines? How do I correct this ?

Ideally, I would get the following output

```
ans = 5
```

Comment: That's the dafult behaviour of the command window! What do you mean by "correcting" this?

Comment: I want the output to be like this `ans = 5`

Comment: AFAIK If you go to Preferences > MATLAB > Command Window, you can only choose between `loose` and `compact` settings for the Numeric display (see [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-window-preferences.html)) But there is no option for what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command to change how the display of variables when printed. In your case, you'll likely want to use the [`'compact'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#input_argument_style) option

```
format compact
```

This will remove all of the unnecessary newlines.

```
2+3
% ans=
%    5
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to display it all on the *same line* because MATLAB's display is built to deal with multi-dimensional data. You *could* overload the `display` command if you really wanted. You can create a folder named `@double` and then a function named `display` inside of that

```
@double/
    display.m
```

Then inside of `display.m` you could do something like this

```
function display(x)
    % If it's a scalar, then show it all on one line
    if isscalar(x)
        fprintf('%s = %g\n', inputname(1), x);
    else
        % Otherwise use the built-in display command
        builtin('display', x)
    end
end
```

Then it will automatically be used when you have a `double` variable

```
>> 2 + 3
% ans = 5
```

If you wanted to overload the display of *other* types of data (`uint16`, `int8`, `uint8`), you would need to do the same as above except put a copy within their `@` folders as well.